# How can I load/use '.pgm' format dataset in Keras?

Tags: input, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I wrote program in Keras related to binary image classification using Neural Networks. I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) from Keras website.

However, in my case, the images using ImageDatagenerator did not load. My images are in '.pgm' format, and I found that ImageDatagenerator reads others file-formats but does not read '.pgm'. What can I do now. Changing the format of the images, will affect the image data and in Steganography, that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Using a lossless format (like PNG) will not affect the image data.

Comment: According [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory), supported image formats: jpeg, png, bmp, gif. Animated gifs are truncated to the first frame.

Comment: According to [this](https://blog.jacob.vi/modifying-tensorflows-mnist-for-beginners-tutorial-to-search-for-cancer-in-mammograms/) you can convert the image from PGM into a numpy array containing the values for each pixel in the image.